# Problem with database.query() in APEX REST @httpput method

Tags: apex, apexrest, database

In APEX REST @httpput method, after DML is done on newKas, saved record having different value in Article_Title__c instead of fetched article title field value from database.query() method.

```
@HttpPut
global static UtilClass.Response manageArticleSubscriptions(Subscription subscriptiondetails)
{
                     CustomObj newKas = new CustomObj();
                     String status = 'Online';
                     String articTitle;
                     String Locale = subscriptiondetails.locale != null ? subscriptiondetails.locale : KM_API_Utils.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
                     String ArticleNumb =  subscriptiondetails.articleid;
                     list<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articleList1 = new list<KnowledgeArticleVersion>();
                     string query = 'Select title from KnowledgeArticleVersion' +
                    ' where ArticleNumber = :ArticleNumb and PublishStatus = :status and language =: Locale'; 
                      articleList1 = Database.query(query);
                      System.debug('dk '+articleList1 );
                     if(articleList != null && articleList.size() > 0) {
                       articTitle = articleList[0].Title;
                       System.debug(' queried articTitle '+articTitle );
                       newKas.Article_Title__c = articTitle ; // wrong value getting updated in Article_Title__c    instead of fetched articTitle
                       System.debug(' mapped articTitle to DML performing object '+articTitle );       
                       insert newKas;
                    }
return new ResponseData.Error(true,Utils.ART_SUCCESFULLY_SUBSCRIBED,200);
}
```

Resolution :-

Then i build the below dynamic soql for fetching title and it got updated perfectly with DML performed object on REST @httpput method.

```
 KnowledgeArticleVersion[] kav = [Select title from KnowledgeArticleVersion where ArticleNumber = :ArticleNumb and PublishStatus ='Online' and language ='en_US'];
 if(kav.size()>0)
 newKas.Article_Title__c = kav[0].Title;
```

From my observation, In REST @httpput method it has some issues when mapping a fetched value by Database.query() to a DML performing object's field.

Comment: This is a bit confusing as to the issue -- are you saying that the value of `articTitle` is wrong when fetched by the query? or that it is right but after the DML is done on `newKas` that the saved record doesn;t have the value of `articTitle` in field `Article_Title__c` ?  Please use [Edit] in your response.

Comment: Edit done and i also updated thread with my workaround which worked out for me, Thanks @cropredy